# Ingress controller nginx exclude IP from basic_auth

Tags: kubernetes, basic-authentication, nginx-ingress

I have ingress controller nginx with basic_auth

In my yaml I have:

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required"
```

Everything works fine, but I need to exclude some IP addresses from basic_auth, and I can`t find a solution for it.

Does ingress have such opportunities?

Comment: _EXCLUDE_ so that IPs cannot pass through basic auth?

Comment: Exclude does mean, IP address, which does not require login and password.

Comment: This sounds to me like you want a [custom server snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet) instead of those annotations you have now, so you can take advantage of the [`if` command](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) in nginx

Answer (score 2):

You want to use custom server snippet and use allow/deny. I find it more elegant solution then the `if` recommentation in the comment above.

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      satisfy  any;
      allow 66.220.144.0/20;
      deny   all;
```

To give credit where credit is due: This answer is based on https://serverfault.com/questions/242218/how-to-disable-http-basic-auth-in-nginx-for-a-specific-ip-range .